# Inno setup - star symbol on page wpPreparing

Tags: inno-setup

On `wpPreparing` I've a star symbol.

[image: example]

However the star symbol does not exist in ISL files or in `[CustomMessages]` sestion.

I've added logging to `CurStepChanged`:

```
  log('CurStepChanged - CurStep: ' + IntToStr(CurStep));
  log('CurStepChanged - Label: ' + WizardForm.StatusLabel.Caption);
  log('CurStepChanged - Label visible: ' + BoolToStr(WizardForm.StatusLabel.Visible));
```

and to `CurPageChanged`:

```
  log('CurPageChanged - CurPage: ' + IntToStr(CurPage));
  log('CurPageChanged - Label: ' + WizardForm.StatusLabel.Caption);
  log('CurPageChanged - Label visible: ' + BoolToStr(WizardForm.StatusLabel.Visible));
```

But still not able to identify the right element.

Whare does the star come from? I want to replace it with custom message.

Answer (score 1):

Gotcha, it's `WizardForm.PreparingLabel`:

```
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPage: Integer);
var RichViewer: TRichEditViewer;
begin
  log('CurPageChanged - CurPage: ' + IntToStr(CurPage));      
  log('CurPageChanged - PreparingLabel: ' + WizardForm.PreparingLabel.Caption);
  log('CurPageChanged - PreparingLabel visible: ' + BoolToStr(WizardForm.PreparingLabel.Visible));
...
```

log:

```
2023-04-19 14:13:20.254   CurPageChanged - CurPage: 11
2023-04-19 14:13:20.254   CurPageChanged - PreparingLabel: *
2023-04-19 14:13:20.254   CurPageChanged - PreparingLabel visible: True
```

Solved with:

```
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPage: Integer);
begin
  if CurPage = wpPreparing then
    begin
      WizardForm.PreparingLabel.Caption := CustomMessage('Preparing');
    end;
end;
```

with custom message:

```
[CustomMessages]
Czech.Preparing=Probíhá příprava instalace, čekejte prosím.
Slovak.Preparing=Prebieha príprava inštalácie, čakajte prosím.
```